# Question about cytoskeleton coordination

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, proteins

I am trying to study for a biology and I am having some confusion over the following topic. Can anyone help explain/ shed some light on the concepts of Rho family GTPases. Is it true that we have Rho activates forimins to relieve  auto inhibition of actin filaments while Rac promotes lamellopodia and Cdc42 works on the leading edge and fillipodia?

Secondly, how are the microtubules involved in cytoskeleton coordination? Do they simply affect Rho and Rac concentrations. How else is the concentrations of these spread throughout the cell as to maintain distinct concentration gradients?

Thank you all for any help!

Comment: The dynamics of Rho GTPase activities are highly complex.. Try to read this [article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3084983/).. it could help you understand or it could make your confusion worst :P